# Java - documentation for "java.net.useSystemProxies" option

Tags: java, proxy

I was surprised to learn that the JVM does not automatically use the system proxy settings.

These need to be specified manually, or can be automatically detected when the `java.net.useSystemProxies` property (default false) is enabled.

I'm looking for more documentation about how this works, but what I've found is quite sparse.
Specifically, my questions where:

- Where is it looking for the proxy settings
- Does it auto-detect for both HTTP & HTTPS
- What is the reason this isn't the default behaviour - is there a drawback?

When I've looked online, all the documentation leads back to documentation from [Oracle for Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html#:%7E:text=java.net.useSystemProxies).
When changing the URL I can get documentation for [Java 10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html#:%7E:text=java.net.useSystemProxies), but nothing beyond that.

I was looking for documentation for both Java 11 and the latest version to see if there were any future changes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My research into documentation was fruitless, but I found partial answers in the Amazon Corretto source code.

**Where is it looking for the proxy settings**

The `java.net.useSystemProxies` property [calls](https://github.com/corretto/corretto-11/blob/develop/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/net/spi/DefaultProxySelector.java#:%7E:text=java.net.useSystemProxies) a native [`init`](https://github.com/corretto/corretto-11/blob/develop/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/net/spi/DefaultProxySelector.java#:%7E:text=native%20boolean%20init()%3B) method, which is implemented per-platform in `DefaultProxySelector.c`.

For Corretto 11, these can be found in [GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Acorretto%2Fcorretto-11+filename%3ADefaultProxySelector.c).

For Windows specifically, these tie into the following `Win32` APIs:

- [WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/ns-winhttp-winhttp_current_user_ie_proxy_config)
- [WINHTTP_AUTOPROXY_OPTIONS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/ns-winhttp-winhttp_autoproxy_options)
- [WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/ns-winhttp-winhttp_proxy_info)
- [WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpgetieproxyconfigforcurrentuser)
- [WinHttpGetProxyForUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpgetproxyforurl)

**Does it auto-detect for both HTTP & HTTPS**

The above APIs only offer HTTP versions so I would assume it sets both.