# Why doesn't java.net.useSystemProxies appear to work?

Tags: java, proxy

Following on from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69943466/3107019).

When I go via a proxy server on my PC, I can't connect to the internet in Java unless the proxy is manually specified - either with no arguments specified, or with `java.net.useSystemProxies`.
I would've expected `java.net.useSystemProxies` to use the system values, but it doesn't seem to.

Take the following simple application, that connects to [AWS' Check IP service](https://checkip.amazonaws.com/) and prints the results to the console.

```
final URI uri = URI.create("https://checkip.amazonaws.com/");

System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Proxy - {0}", ProxySelector.getDefault().select(uri)));

System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("IP - {0}", HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(HttpRequest.newBuilder(uri).build(), BodyHandlers.ofString()).body()));
```

When run, it prints the following:

```
Proxy - [DIRECT]
IP - {MY PUBLIC IP}
```

I then set my PC to use a proxy that I found on [this website](https://hidemy.name/en/proxy-list/?type=hs#list):

[image]

When I access [AWS' Check IP service](https://checkip.amazonaws.com/), the IP returned is now that of the proxy - `176.9.117.112`.

Now when I re-run my application, without any arguments, it still connects - but not via the proxy:

```
Proxy - [DIRECT]
IP - {MY PUBLIC IP}
```

With the `-D"java.net.useSystemProxies"=true` argument set, the behaviour is the same - still not via the proxy:

```
Proxy - [DIRECT]
IP - {MY PUBLIC IP}
```

Finally, when I manually specify the proxy server via the arguments `-Dhttp.proxyHost=176.9.117.112 -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttps.proxyHost=176.9.117.112 -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128`, it's clear the traffic is going via the proxy:

```
Proxy - [HTTP @ 176.9.117.112/<unresolved>:3128]
IP - 176.9.117.112
```

So my question is - why doesn't `java.net.useSystemProxies` use system proxies?

Comment: `-D"java.net.useSystemProxies"=true` are qotes in this typo?
Did you try `-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true`
Did you trye setting `System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");` in code?

Comment: @BartekJablonski ``-D"java.net.useSystemProxies"=true`` vs ``-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true`` both return the same results.
``System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");`` gives the same result as well.
No proxies used for any.

Comment: What version of Java is this?

Comment: @Codebling I can reproduce this on Java 11 & Java 15. I've not tried any others.

Comment: You're not using a Security Manager, right?

Comment: @Codebling not to my knowledge, no.